# Best pratice on using `tf.compat.v1.metrics.auc`?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, auc

I try to migrate my code from tf1.* to tf2, while in [tf2 doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/metrics/auc) it says that `tf.compat.v1.metrics.auc` is deprecated because "The value of AUC returned by this may race with the update". This statement is vague to me. Does it mean that it can't be used in multithreading context? If not, in what situation can I use this function?

Answer (score 0):

`tf.compat.v1.metrics.auc` has been moved under tf.keras.

As mentioned in the error message itself you can start using [tf.keras.metrics.AUC](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/AUC) in Tf2.
There are some changes in hyper parameters in the updated version, details with the example can be found in the above mentioned document.